# Typescript Factory Pattern implementation with common functions

Tags: typescript

I have the following interface

```
export interface Parent {
   some_foo: string,
   some_function(some_param): Promise<void>
}
```

I have the following two implementations

```
export class ChildOne implements Parent {
  constructor(some_foo) {
     this.some_foo = some_foo
     this.another_var = "one"
  }
  some_function(some_param) {
      // some logic using this.some_foo, this.another_var and some_param
  }
}

export class ChildTwo implements Parent {
  constructor(some_foo) {
     this.some_foo = some_foo
     this.another_var = "two"
  }
  some_function(some_param) {
      // EXACT SAME logic using this.some_foo, this.anothervar, some_param 
  }
}
```

The issue I am facing is that ChildOne and ChildTwo has the exact same code for the some_function (and other functions)
They only differ by their constructors

Questions:

1. Where should this common code lie? I know its not possible to put this inside the interface
2. Would it make more sense to use an abstract class here to fit common code in? I should mention that the interface type is used in a lot of other class member definitons

PS: I have a factory method that based on a parameter returns an instance of ChildOne or ChildTwo

Comment: Interfaces should not contain implementations (as that's quite counterintutive), they only specify the **shape** (or syntax if you will) for classes to follow. For your specific case an abstract class seem to be adequate though.

Comment: @sandmann I have various other class definitions and function parameters that have parent: Parent
If I change Parent to an abstract class (to add common code in abstract class), how will that input params be updated?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a [mixin](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html), which lets you apply abstract implementations using composition rather than inheritance:

```
interface Parent {
  some_foo: string;
  some_function(some_param): Promise<void>;
}

// utility type so that we can use the parent interface minus the function to be mixed-in
type PartialParent = Omit<Parent, 'some_function'>;

// define the implemting class without some_function
class PartialChildOne implements PartialParent {
  some_foo: string;
  another_var: string;
  constructor(some_foo: string) {
    this.some_foo = some_foo;
    this.another_var = 'one';
  }
}

class PartialChildTwo implements PartialParent {
  some_foo: string;
  another_var: string;
  constructor(some_foo: string) {
    this.some_foo = some_foo;
    this.another_var = 'two';
  }
}

// we can provide constraints for our mixin - see below
type HasAnotherVar = { another_var: string };

// define the constraints - must be a class, must be PartialParent AND satisfy HasAnotherVar
type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
type PartialParentConstructor = Constructor<PartialParent & HasAnotherVar>;

// here we apply the abstract function we need - taken from the ts docs - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html
function applySomeFunction<TBase extends PartialParentConstructor>(
  Base: TBase
) {
  return class WithSomeFunction extends Base {
    async some_function(some_param: string): Promise<void> {
      console.log(this.some_foo, this.another_var, some_param);
    }
  };
}

// then we can apply the mixin to create composed classes, which each have some_function defined
const ChildOne = applySomeFunction(PartialChildOne);
const ChildTwo = applySomeFunction(PartialChildTwo);

// use the classes
const c1 = new ChildOne('foo');
const c2 = new ChildTwo('bar');

// typescript is totally happy with this
c1.some_function('hello');
c2.some_function('goodbye');

// and the classes meet the `Parent` interface so typescript is happy with this casting as well
let asParent = c1 as Parent;
asParent = c2 as Parent;
```

Comment: That is a great suggestion @matt clarson, this wouldnt work if in case down the line ChildOne and ChildTwo were to have different implementations right?

Comment: no if they had different implementations of `some_function` you wouldn't be able to use the same mixin to implement them - but doing it this way rather than using an abstract base class means that it would be a lot easier to separate the two classes later on if you neede to, right - because the mixin just patches individual pieces of functionality rather than the whole thing